# Methods to inform the user that something has changed in the background

Tags: hidden, infographic, information-design

We are working on an application that involves analyzing images. The end-user will be looking at those images and might notice something strange... something that he needs to report about.

This user might create 1 or more annotations per image.. while, creating such an annotation will force the system to automatically generate a copy of that image, including its new annotation(s). This all happens in the background, since the complete list of annotated images is 'hidden' under some drop-down element.

We do want to inform the user that new annotated image(s) are generated.

What are best practices to inform the user about such a hidden event:
 - Textual (explaining textually what happened; e.g. Android toast, or tooltip popping-up somewhere) 
 - Animation (the image/annotation is animated; e.g. dropped into some sort of bucket)
 - Flashing objects (related object will flash shortly; e.g. the drop-down element flashes 3 times)

or can you think of more/other methods?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem.

Technically, anything pulsing, either in size or in color, will do (Slack is using a pulsing circular macro icon to attract users' attention to certain parts of the UI), but if there are several new annotations, all pulsing in the background, it can be annoying.

Location of the annotation is important.
Annotation are texts, so I would use a squarish text bubble icon, popping up at the locus of an image and fading out in 3 seconds after staying 5 seconds. If you would like users to read the new annotation (otherwise there's no sense in notifying about it), keep it static longer so that users will have enough time to hover or tap.

If annotations are generally short and of importance, I would show them, popping up in a bigger bubble/tooltip and fading away if not hovered. Pointer of a bubble should point at the locus.

Comment: Thank you Zoe. This solution had my preference as well. We will start doing some user validation on this, together with the option @DasBeasto provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple facebook style notification next to the dropdown that signifies that there are new images and how many new images there are:

[image]

(excuse the poorly put otgether MS Paint picture)